# Spark jobs not visible on yarn application list

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm experimenting around dataproc spark cluster having 1 master and 2 worker node of type n2-standard-4. Running the spark code on associated Jupyter notebook via both jupyter 'python3 notebook' and jupyter 'pyspark notebook'.

When I run the spark jobs on jupyter 'pyspark notebook', can see the jobs in yarn web UI as well as command line on master node using yarn application --list. However when I run the same spark job on jupyter 'python notebook', do not see the jobs on both yarn web UI and command line, even after job has been successfully completed and generated results. However in both cases, jobs are visible post completion on spark history server.

what could be the reason for jobs not listed/visible on yarn when ran on jupyter 'python notebook'? does jupyter 'python notebook' run on just single node instead of using distributed spark nodes?

Comment: In Python3 notebook, you need to explicitly create a SparkSession, before that there's no Spark/YARN application. Did you do that?

Comment: Apologies, somehow missed to respond. yes, running the complete spark application(minimal code to test, same code copied from  PySpark notebook) on Python3 notebook, including session creation.